# Automated Email System driven by SQL Server SSIS alternatives

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I apologize in advance if this question is inappropriate for this forum. 
I'm currently developing an `Automated Email System` using `SSIS` which searches the database and generates emails based on given conditions.
 The reason I've chosen `SSIS` is that the DBMS for the system is `SQL Server` and most of my current findings recommend this tool. 
I wonder if there is any alternatives suitable to my project. I've been researching this subject for a while but google shows only readymade solutions.

Comment: What are your requirements ? Eg. I want e-mail ! Then yahoo, google, hotmail (yuck) will be fine. I want apps too -gmail. Makes sense ?

Comment: @Borat The requirements are that the process should pick up flagged emails records from the database, generate appropriate email with summary data of user related records from the same database (the system already generates XML Excel) and send the email to address retrieved.

Comment: I am not an SSIS expert, but I would go with SSIS for this. Is there any reason why you feel that SSIS might not be suitable for the task  ?

Comment: SQL Server is no reason to use SSIS. SSIS is optimised for moving and transforming large volumes of data. You will find this much easier if you use a more appropriate tool. You can build this in SSIS but you will probably just find yourself writing loads of script that would be much easier to build in a .Net app.

Comment: @ElectricLlama At the moment I consider to write script utilizing `.Net.Mail` library, which is quite straight forward. What would you suggest ?

Comment: All I suggest is don't assume that because you have data in SQL Server that you have to build everything in SSIS. But they only way you'll discover this is to try it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would use SSRS (Reporting Services) for this.

I would define an SSRS report for the "summary data of user related records".  I would deploy that report to either the native "Report Manager" portal or SharePoint.  Then I would define a Data-Driven Subscription which which can use a SQL query for "searches the database and generates emails based on given conditions".

Note that Data-Driven Subscriptions require specific editions of SSRS:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Reporting

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't aware of that technology, will have a look.